# How to add an extra line that also have a pattern in file containing a pattern in previous line?

Tags: shell-script, awk, sed, grep, perl

I have a file -

```
something
\title{\hypertarget{A64L}{A64L(3)}}
something
\title{\hypertarget{MALLOC}{MALLOC(3)}}
something
\title{\hypertarget{STRCMP}{STRCMP(3)}}
```

The word in `{}` may be anything, but same in consecutive `{}`.
I want to get

```
something
\title{\hypertarget{A64L}{A64L(3)}}
\addcontentsline{A64L}
something
\title{\hypertarget{MALLOC}{MALLOC(3)}}
\addcontentsline{MALLOC}
something
\title{\hypertarget{STRCMP}{STRCMP(3)}}
\addcontentsline{STRCMP}
```

I tried following, but failed.

```
sed -e /\\\\title\{\\\\hypertarget\{.*\}\{.*\(3\)\}\}/a\\\\\\addcontentsline\{\&\} filename
```

This is an extension of https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/408244/how-to-make-toc-without-having-any-section-parts-name

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure exactly what you're trying to capture, but

```
$ sed 's/\\title{\\hypertarget\({[^}]*}\).*/&\n\\addcontentsline\1/' file
something
\title{\hypertarget{A64L}{A64L(3)}}
\addcontentsline{A64L}
something
\title{\hypertarget{MALLOC}{MALLOC(3)}}
\addcontentsline{MALLOC}
something
\title{\hypertarget{STRCMP}{STRCMP(3)}}  
\addcontentsline{STRCMP}
```

Comment: a `\` before `addcontent...`

Comment: @alhelal apologies - should be fixed now

Comment: yes. fixed now.

Answer (score 1):

```
j=`grep -o "{[0-9A-Z]\{4\}}" k1.txt | sed -r "s/\s+//g" | sed '/^$/d'`;
grep -B1 "$j" k1.txt  | sed "/title/s/.*/&\n\\\addcontentsline$j/g";
for i in `grep -o "{[A-Z]\{6\}}" k1.txt`; do
  grep -B1 $i k1.txt| sed "/title/s/.*/&\n\\\addcontentsline$i/g";
done
```

Output:

```
something
\title{\hypertarget{A64L}{A64L(3)}}
\addcontentsline{A64L}
something
\title{\hypertarget{MALLOC}{MALLOC(3)}}
\addcontentsline{MALLOC}
something
\title{\hypertarget{STRCMP}{STRCMP(3)}}
\addcontentsline{STRCMP}
```